# How to replace an escape char?

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I'm trying to sanitize/standardize some user input for file directories. Windows does the `\` and *nux/*nix do the `/`. In java `\` must be escaped to `\\` otherwise you get compile error.

How can I read `\` from user input and replace it with `/` ?

```
private String escapeDirs(String raw) {
    return raw.replace("\\", "/");
}
```

This does not work... presumably because it's read in as a `\` not a `\\`. But I can't do `raw.replace("\", "/");`...

Sample user input: `C:\User\SomeUser\SomeDir`

Comment: try to do like: `return raw.replace("\\\\", "/");`

Comment: Can you provide a sample input of user?

Comment: Sample user input:   `C:\User\SomeUser\SomeDir`

Comment: Use `raw.replaceAll("\\","/");`

Comment: What do you mean that it "does not work"? What do you get instead of what you expected with your sample input?

Comment: @ExtremeCoders - Why use `replaceAll`? There's no need for using regular expressions for this simple replacement.

Comment: +1 I agree with @TedHopp about using `replace()` is enough. `replaceAll()` method's name is misleading :\. They should name them `replaceAll()` and `replaceRegex()` instead.

Comment: The code posted now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
private String escapeDirs(String raw) {
    return raw.replace("\\", "/");
}
```

The `replace()` method in fact replaces *all* occurrences of the target,

It seems you originally were using `replaceAll()`, which replaces a *regex*. It make that work, do tis:

```
private String escapeDirs(String raw) {
    return raw.replace("\\\\", "/");
}
```

The regex for a backslash is `\\`, and in java the String constant needs each one to be escaped, hence the 4 needed.

Answer (score 1):

if you are building a solution for windows and unix both this is one of the issues that developer need to take care

There are two approaches

1. Handle the escape characters for Windows seperately using \ and do the paths for unix seperately
2. Use / in the paths for windows as well , the same would be used in unix and windows

example

In  Windows

c:/temp works the same like c:\temp

In Unix

/tmp/

Hope that helps

Thanks
Abhi

Comment: But one day, you encounter `\\ALPHA\C:\Temp` or even just `\\?\C:\Very\very\long\path\longer\than\258\characters`. Now what?

Comment: as per the input SnakeDoc gave , i have purposed the solution."Sample user input: C:\User\SomeUser\SomeDir"

Answer (score 1):

Use the [character version of replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29) instead of the string version.

```
private static String escapeDirs(String raw) {
  return raw.replace('\\', '/');
}
```

Comment: Why would that do anything different?

Comment: @TedHopp, I agree that there shouldn't be a difference, but with single character inputs there's no confusion about whether multiple characters in the input correspond to one in the output, so if it still doesn't do what you want then you know to look elsewhere for the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static String backlashReplace(String myStr){
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    final StringCharacterIterator iterator = new StringCharacterIterator(myStr);
    char character =  iterator.current();
    while (character != CharacterIterator.DONE ){

      if (character == '\\') {
         result.append("/");
      }
       else {
        result.append(character);
      }


      character = iterator.next();
    }
    return result.toString();
  }
```